# How to select the country with the min population

Tags: sql, min

I know this is a very easy question but i need someone to explain the thought process behind this query.
I have a big table of data related to countries. I want to see which country has the minimum population so i use the following query

```
SELECT country, MIN(population) AS min_pop FROM countries_by_population;
```

it returns an error that the country should be in the aggregate or in the GROUP BY. I'm confused; why? shouldnt this query just see the min(population) and return that with the country name?

after this i add the country to a GROUP BY like this

```
SELECT country, MIN(population) AS min_pop FROM countries_by_population GROUP BY country;
```

and i get a table of all the countries with their population in alphabetic order. how did this happen?

after explaining this can someone talk through the thought process of the correct query?
Thanks.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: you have indexes in database?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` operator tells your database to aggregate a result from each group of countries together.  In the case of your (correct) query, the DB will return the `country` and minimum population for each set of records of a given country.  And good on you for getting the query right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is about query, i.e., filter and read/write.

1. When you do:

   `SELECT country, MIN(population) AS min_pop FROM countries_by_population;`
   you intended to select countries with the minimum population, and that logic is right--"select countries" and "with the minimum population". However what's going on here is that, on the one hand, "select countries" has no filtering and means just read data, returning the countries from the tuples filtered by the potential "where" clause (which you don't have). On the other hand, `MIN()` returns the minimum value. Basically there is a mismatch here: you want to pair the countries with the minimum population but SQL does not know how.
2. Group By means group tuples with the same value. In this case you just group by countries with their, maybe, names and since countries are unique, their will be no group of more than two. Therefore basically nothing happens **visually**.
3. To do your task there are several ways and one of them is that you could firstly query about the value of minimum population using

`select MIN(population) from countries_by_population`,

then you could do

`select country from countries_by_population where population = minipop`, either in nested query or you could do it in separate ways.

Comment: this is the final query i used SELECT country, population
FROM countries_by_population 
WHERE population=(SELECT MIN(population) FROM countries_by_population); is there any way to shorten it? thanks for the detailed reply btw.

Comment: @Newton You are welcome :). Besides, I thought this is simplified enough and you can do with that

Comment: @Newton It just came to me that you could use `select top 1 * from countries_by_population order by populatioin asc`. It _looks_ more simple but, as I said, this is already simplified enough.

Answer (score 0):

The [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm) requires the columns specified in the mathematical functions to be specified in it.

Example: Consider **Employee** table

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY NAME;
```

This will return a result something like this

```
+----------+-------------+
| NAME     | SUM(SALARY) |
+----------+-------------+
| A        | 15000.00    |
| B        | 25000.00    |
| C        | 35000.00    |
+----------+-------------+
```

If you don't specify the column in `GROUP BY` clause like

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS
```

you'll face the below error message.

```
'Column Name'  is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `GROUP BY` but what you could do is

```
SELECT TOP 1 country, MIN(population) AS min_pop 
  FROM countries_by_population
 GROUP BY country 
 ORDER BY 2;
```

Assuming you're using MSSQL.

Comment: Please take a closer look at the question, the OP is asking why the result is in alphabetic order, he's not getting any error from the SQL.

Comment: Subject clearly states what he needs "How to select the country with the min population"